# Assign a dictionary value to a variable where key == list[element]

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

`c = d[s[0]]` where `c` is a new variable, `d` is a dictionary, and `s` is a list.

What I'm attempting to do is assign the value of a key that is the same as the first element from my list to `c`. I know the key is in the dictionary, and that the first element of the list is the same as that key. How do I assign the value of that key to a variable? The code I wrote gives me an out of index error.

However, the code:

```
a = s[0]
c = d[a]
```

works.
Why doesn't the first attempt work?
This is for Python 2.7 on windows

Comment: I don't mind getting minused, but please be kind enough to indicate why.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it's most likely due to the fact that it's completely impossible to give you an accurate answer with what you have given us. You didn't include the relevant code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the code I wrote any longer. Essentially what I had was a list, and a histogram dictionary of that list. I sorted the list then took the first element and attempted to pull the value of the matching key. My code should have worked as posted by @Srikar Appal, but for some reason kept getting out of index error. Unfortunately I couldn't tell if it was out of index on the list or on the dictionary. I assumed it was a problem with the way I wrote the statement, since the alternate method worked with no problems ever.

Comment: upvoted to counteract downvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it is not working for you. Maybe your `list` is not populated after all. This should work -

```
>>> d={'world':'hunger'}
>>> s=['world']
>>> d[s[0]]
'hunger'
>>> c = d[s[0]]
>>> c
'hunger'
>>>
```

Also Python dictionaries have a nifty feature called [`has_key`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_has_key.htm). It checks if a key is present in that dict or not. I use this to prevent `KeyError` Exceptions... You could consider using this to prevent untoward crashes.